# Centering a Logo across multiple resolutions

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a logo that i am trying to center on a page. Dead center from left to right. The problem that i have been facing is when i view it on different monitor sizes/resolutions it never lines up to be centered. I get it right on one resolution/size and then when i go to work on my smaller monitor it doesn't line up.  Does this need to be accomplished with multiple stylesheets or a dynamic theme?  I am coding the site in ASP.NET and have themes set up. This can be changed if needed.

```
<body>
<div class="wrap_1">
    <form id="form1"  runat="server">
    <!-- LOGO WRAP STARTS HERE-->

        <asp:Image SkinID="DefaultLogo" runat="server"/>

  <div style="background-color: #c5e8ea;"  >
  <!-- TITLE WRAP STARTS HERE-->
    <div class="wrap">
<div>
    <h1 style="padding-left:2em;">BLAH BLAH BLAH </h1>
    <h2 style="padding-left:5em;">BLAH BLAH BLAH </h2>
    <div>
 <!--CONTROLS -->
 <ul id="home-menu">
    <li>
        <asp:Button SkinID="Button1" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Reinstall.aspx"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <asp:Button SkinID="Button2" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Registration.aspx" />
    </li>
</ul>


    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
    </form>
```

CSS

```
.DefaultLogo {
     margin: auto auto;
}

.wrap_1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrap {
    margin: auto auto;
}
```

Comment: Show us your HTML so we have something to work with. Generally to center something horizontally you just need style="text-align:center;" on the <p> that your logo is in. Couls also be that your parent container isn't getting centered, but we'll never know without any code...

Comment: Could it be .wrap_1 { margin: 0 auto; }? Why zero here?

Comment: I think you have also made a small mistake on SkinID (see my answer below, I've edited it to reflect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the width of your image is always going to be a certain width, let's say 300px, then you can apply this css to it:

```
#Logo {
    width: 300px;
    height: 110px;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
}
```

I would try to go with the "margin: 0 auto" choice though.

Comment: Thank you for your post. It seems to be doing what i wanted.  Why did you say go with the Margin:0 auto choice? i had that and it was never dead center and it would shift on my based on resolution. that is why i started this post.

Comment: I usually prefer using margin: 0 auto for little centering items like that.  I do have a suggestion for you, however, to see if this will make your margin: 0 auto; work.  I'm a little curious now haha.  Have you tried setting a fixed width on your logo container, and also add a float: none?  I'm a little confused as to why you're having trouble with margin: 0 auto.  Either way, I'm glad my solution helped!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve that using CSS only.

```
#theCoolestLogoEver{
  margin: auto auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I just tried that, but when i do that it pushes it to the left.  It is not in the center of the screen. (i could be using incorrect wording.)

Comment: When you say "pushes to the left" - do you mean all the way? Or just a fraction? Also, what exactly happens if you resize the window width while viewing the page? Does it seem to move with the other elements or does it move faster/slower horizontally?

Comment: All the way as if it didn't have any positioning

Comment: It could be a number of reasons. I think i'll agree with the others that we need to see some code. My guess is that you're unknowingly inheriting some style from above. What does FireBug tell you when you hover your element?

Comment: Thank you for all your help i just edited my original post. Take it easy on my me i am self taught so alot could be wrong.

Comment: Also, not saying that it is wrong - just different from what i'd do. Why using <asp:Image> instead of good, old, plain <img>? (Same for button.) Besides that, you're welcome to format the code so it's a minimal example without any excessive line spacing. Nothing serious but easier for our eyes to read.  :)

Comment: thank you. I swear it was cleaner when i first started writing it but this was what i considered a simplistic thing that created a mess.

Comment: Hehe, all projects are clean in the beginning. Then, the programmers put in a lot of bugs and strange, sometimes incomprehensible stuff...

Answer (score 0):

You can give your image a ID or class and set that in css or just set the style inline to

```
<img src="blah" style="margin: auto auto;"/>
```

or in CSS

```
<img src="blah" name="moo"/>

#blah { 
    margin: auto auto;
}
```

or in CSS using classes

```
<img src="blah" class="moo"/>

.blah { 
   margin: auto auto;
}
```

I have also noticed your using SkinID in your contorls, I don't think it does what you think it does. It sets what Skin should be used on the control so instead of

```
<asp:Image SkinID="DefaultLogo" runat="server"/>
```

try

```
<asp:Image runat="server" CssClass="moo"/>
```

and have you CSS Set to

```
.blah { 
   margin: auto auto;
}
```

Comment: I just tried that on a blank template to test it. It is pushing it in the upper left hand corner as if the values where margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

Comment: @user1108957 SkinID doesn't do what you think it does, it sets the skin associated with the control, it doesn't set the ID of the control. Try applying a class to the image and using that instead. Otherwise you need to work with the "clientID" property of the control and use that, but thats a little more complex. See my updated answer

Comment: I am not using the skinid like you explained.  I didnt copy n paste my skin file to show you the format. They share the same identifier. "DefaultLogo" is also the CssClass. I can move the image anywhere i want. But it shifts based on screen size.resolution which is throwing off my centering. Thanks for all the help so far!